# How to add pick list value into test class dynamically

Tags: unit-test, class

I want to add pick list value in test class i.e when i select pick list value it should be updated/added  in the corresponding test class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not hard (Assuming the value to be passed to the test class is the default picklist value)..

Create a new Static Method which would retrieve the default picklist

**Method 1: Apex Method**

```
public static string retrieveDefaultPicklist(String sObjectName , String picklistFieldApi) {
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldSchema = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(picklistFieldApi).getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> schemaList = fieldSchema.getPicklistValues();
    string defaultPicklistLabel;

    if (!schemaList.isEmpty()) {
        for( Schema.PicklistEntry schema : schemaList){
            valuesList.put(s.getValue(), s.getLabel());
            if (schema.isDefaultValue()) {
                defaultPicklistLabel = schema.getValue()
            }
        } 
    }
    return defaultPicklistLabel;
}
```

call this function when assigning the picklist value in the test class.

to retrieve values other than the default values the method can be updated

**Method 2: Custom Label**
A custom label can also be created referring to the value and assigning it in apex test class (the value and then the value can be updated on a request basis in setup)

```
System.Label.Label_name
```